# Add-Migration without parameterless DbContext and DbContextFactory constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

My application has no parameterless constructor at my `DbContext` implementation and I don't like to provide a parameterless constructor to a `IDbContextFactory<>` implementation.

The reason is I want to keep control where the DbContext points to. That's why all my constructors will ask for the ConnectionStringProvider.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    internal MyDbContext(IConnectionStringProvider provider) : base(provider.ConnectionString) {}
}
```

and

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringProvider _provider;
    public MyContextFactory(IConnectionStringProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
    public MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext(_provider.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

I definitely don’t want to add a default constructor! I already did that and it crashed on production because of the wrong connection strings inside the wrong App.config or assuming a default connection string like the default constructor of `DbContext` does. I would like use the same infrastructure on

- Debug/Relase (and only inject a different `IConnectionStringProvider`)
- Calling `Add-Migration` script
- Running `DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()`

Currently I get some of those messages:

> The context factory type 'Test.MyContextFactory' does not have a public parameterless constructor. Either add a public parameterless constructor, create an IDbContextFactory implementation in the context assembly, or register a context factory using DbConfiguration.

**---UPDATE---**

This might be a duplicate of [How do I inject a connection string into an instance of IDbContextFactory<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734496) but it has no solution. I explain why:

- I always use `Add-Migration` with connection string, so how can I provide a `DbContext` or `IDbContextFactory<>` that consumes it? Instead of parameterless constructors?

  > Add-Migration MyMigration -ConnectionStringName "MyConnectionString"
- The same problem here: I use `DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()` which also asks for parameterless `DbContext` or `IDbContextFactory<>` implementations.

As far as I understand EntityFramework violates encapsulation 
[by implying default constructors](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/30/DesignSmellDefaultConstructor) and causes 
[temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) which is not fail-safe. So please propose a solution without parameterless constructors.

Comment: You might want to consider a facade with constructor injection (aka default values supplied by a static Service Locator): http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Thanks for the comment. But as far as I understand it needs a parameterless constructor. That's not what I want. I want to get `Add-Migration` or at least `DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations()` running without a parameterless constructor. Because there are no default values I can provide.

Comment: you have to provide some value for the parameter at some point - that's going to be the default value, resolved by a static Service Locator, which needs a specific injection/registration. anyway, this solution is more a workaround than a *good* solution ... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I inject a connection string into an instance of IDbContextFactory<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734496/how-do-i-inject-a-connection-string-into-an-instance-of-idbcontextfactoryt)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair No. The marked solution implements `IDbContextFactory<DataStore>` without a constructor, so the default (parameterless) constructor is still in place.

Comment: Actually, yes: it circumnavigates the exact same issue you are facing by utilizing `Database.SetInitializer<>` and shifting the dependency on the connection solely to the context instead additionally to the factory. And yes, it involves creating a custom `IDatabaseInitializer`.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair 1) The non-marked solution mentioning the `Database.SetInitializer<>` doesn't work for calling the `Add-Migration` script. 2) I willingly would like to call `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyDbMigrationsConfiguration>(true));` and `MyContext.Database.Initialize(false);`. But I also would like to check `DbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any()` instead running database initialization everytime. And `DbMigrator` doesn't have a `useSuppliedContext` switch. 3) Why must I create my own `IDatabaseInitializer`?

Answer (score 4):

> I always use `Add-Migration` with connection string, so how can I provide a `DbContext` or `IDbContextFactory<>` that consumes it? Instead of parameterless constructors?

After spending some time reverse-engineering Entity Framework it turns out the answer is: you can't!

Here's what happens when you run `Add-Migration` (with no default constructor):

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: The target context 'Namespace.MyContext' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

Let's have a look at the `DbMigrator` constructor. When run from the `Add-Migration` command, `usersContext` is null, `configuration.TargetDatabase` is **not** null and contains information passed from the command-line parameters such as `-ConnectionStringName`, `-ConnectionString` and `-ConnectionProviderName`. So `new DbContextInfo(configuration.ContextType, configuration.TargetDatabase)` is called.

```
internal DbMigrator(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, bool calledByCreateDatabase) : base(null)
{
    Check.NotNull(configuration, "configuration");
    Check.NotNull(configuration.ContextType, "configuration.ContextType");
    _configuration = configuration;
    _calledByCreateDatabase = calledByCreateDatabase;
    _existenceState = existenceState;
    if (usersContext != null)
    {
        _usersContextInfo = new DbContextInfo(usersContext);
    }
    else
    {
        _usersContextInfo = ((configuration.TargetDatabase == null) ?
            new DbContextInfo(configuration.ContextType) :
            new DbContextInfo(configuration.ContextType, configuration.TargetDatabase));
        if (!_usersContextInfo.IsConstructible)
        {
            throw Error.ContextNotConstructible(configuration.ContextType);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

For the `DbMigrator` not to throw, the `DbContextInfo` instance must be constructible. Now, let's look at the `DbContextInfo` constructor. For the `DbContextInfo` to be constructible, both `CreateActivator()` and `CreateInstance()` must not return null.

```
private DbContextInfo(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func<IDbDependencyResolver> resolver = null)
{
    _resolver = (resolver ?? ((Func<IDbDependencyResolver>)(() => DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver)));
    _contextType = contextType;
    _modelProviderInfo = modelProviderInfo;
    _appConfig = config;
    _connectionInfo = connectionInfo;
    _activator = CreateActivator();
    if (_activator != null)
    {
        DbContext dbContext = CreateInstance();
        if (dbContext != null)
        {
            _isConstructible = true;
            using (dbContext)
            {
                _connectionString = DbInterception.Dispatch.Connection.GetConnectionString(dbContext.InternalContext.Connection, new DbInterceptionContext().WithDbContext(dbContext));
                _connectionStringName = dbContext.InternalContext.ConnectionStringName;
                _connectionProviderName = dbContext.InternalContext.ProviderName;
                _connectionStringOrigin = dbContext.InternalContext.ConnectionStringOrigin;
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual bool IsConstructible => _isConstructible;
}
```

`CreateActivator` basically searches for a parameterless constructor of either your DbContext type or your `IDbContextFactory<MyContext>` implementation and returns a `Func<MyContext>`. Then `CreateInstance` calls that activator. Unfortunately, the `DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo` parameter of the `DbContextInfo` constructor is not used by the activator but is only applied later after the context instance is created (irrelevant code removed for brevity):

```
public virtual DbContext CreateInstance()
{
    dbContext = _activator == null ? null : _activator();
    dbContext.InternalContext.ApplyContextInfo(this);
    return dbContext;
}
```

Then, inside `ApplyContextInfo`, the magic happens: the connection info (from `_connectionInfo`) is overridden on the newly created context.

So, given that you **must** have a parameterless constructor, my solution is similar to yours, but with a few more aggressive checks.

1. The default constructor is only added when compiling in *Debug* configuration.
2. The default constructor throws if not called from the `Add-Migration` command.

Here's what my context look like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyContextConfiguration>(useSuppliedContext: true));
    }

#if DEBUG
    public MyContext()
    {
        var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
        var isMigration = stackTrace.GetFrames()?.Any(e => e.GetMethod().DeclaringType?.Namespace == typeof(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade).Namespace) ?? false;
        if (!isMigration)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The {GetType().Name} default constructor must be used exclusively for running Add-Migration in the Package Manager Console.");
    }
#endif
    // ...
}
```

Then I can finally run

```
Add-Migration -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

And for running the migrations I haven't found a solution using a `DbMigrator` explicitly, so I use the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` database initializer with `useSuppliedContext: true` as explained in [How do I inject a connection string into an instance of IDbContextFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734496/how-do-i-inject-a-connection-string-into-an-instance-of-idbcontextfactoryt/32478553#32478553) .

Answer (score 2):

**Ok, I guess there's no answer!**

That's why I'd like to announce my *stomach aching workaround*: As there's no way to get rid of the default constructor ([and satisfy principles of encapsulation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/30/DesignSmellDefaultConstructor/)) I provide an empty constructor with an intentionally false connection string. So in case it will be used for anything else than migration it fails on runtime as early as possible and in all enviroments (Debug/Integration/Release).

```cs
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MyDbContextFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public MyDbContextFactory()
    {
        _connectionString = "MIGRATION_ONLY_DONT_USE_ITS_FAKE!";
    }

    public MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

(I wouldn't consider this as an answer so feel free to post a better solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to migrate to Entity Framework Core. They have thought about that issue and there's a [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(string[] args)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1.createdbcontext?view=efcore-2.1) interface where `args` are the arguments provided by the design-time service.

But beware, as of Entity Framework Core 2.1 this feature is not yet implemented! See [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory) for the documentation and [Tools: Flow arguments into IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8332) on GitHub to follow the progress and be notified when this will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Migrate Initializer that takes a connection string as constructur parameter then you could pass it to the Migration Constructor so it can use that connection string

```
 public class MigrateInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>
    {
        public MigrateInitializer(string connectionString) : base(true, new Configuration() { TargetDatabase=new  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo(connectionString,"System.Data.SqlClient") })
        {
        }

    }
```

The pass it to the MigrateInitializer

public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateInitializer(connectionString));
        }

}

Thats it now the migration will use the connection string your provided

Answer (score 1):

To extend answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778826/9941549 : the feature has been implemented finally, works ok with EfCore.Design 5.x package.

To use:

- in project used to run ef tools against, create class implementing `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourContext>`,
- implement method `YourContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)`,
- args will be populated with command-line args passed to ef tools commands after double dash (e.g. `dotnet ef migration add -- this will be passed`)
- EF requires only that method return context ready to use - thus you're free to use params as you want (require connection string as a parameter, path to config, anything)